# Color coding plotly text annotations according to a vector or gradient

Tags: r, annotations, plotly, heatmap, color-coding

I have integer data that I want to plot using `R`'s `plotly` as a `heatmap` with the elements of the `heatmap` color coded by the size of the integer data. I also want to annotate each element by a text annotation of the integer and also color code that text by the size of the integer data.

Here's the data:

```
library(dplyr)

pal <- grDevices::colorRamp(c("black","gray"))
set.seed(1)
df <- rbind(data.frame(col = "a",
                 group = paste0("g",1:20),
                 n = as.integer(runif(20, 1, 20))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(text.col = rgb(pal((n - min(n))/diff(range(n))),max=255)),
  data.frame(col = "b",
             group = paste0("g",1:20),
             n = as.integer(runif(20, 1, 40))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(text.col = rgb(pal((n - min(n))/diff(range(n))),max=255)))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = paste0("g",1:20))
```

So my `heatmap` will have 20 rows corresponding to `df$group` and 2 columns corresponding to `df$col`. As you can see I'm specifying the color of each element in `df`.

Here's a `data.frame` specifying the color range of the `heatmap`'s background color, for each `df$col`:

```
colors.df <- data.frame(col = c("a", "b"),
                        fill.low = c("#a6c4ba", "#f2edda"),
                        fill.high = c("#4e8a75", "#b49823"),
                        stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And here's my `plotly` code:

```
lapply(c("a","b"), function(l){
  col.df <- dplyr::filter(df, col == l)
  n.text <- as.character(col.df$n)
  plotly::plot_ly(ygap = 1, z = col.df$n, x = col.df$col, y =col.df$group,
                  colors = grDevices::colorRamp(c(dplyr::filter(colors.df,col == l)$fill.low, dplyr::filter(colors.df,col == l)$fill.high)), type = "heatmap") %>%
    plotly::hide_colorbar() %>%
    plotly::add_annotations(font = list(color = col.df$text.col, size = 8),text = n.text,x = col.df$col,y = col.df$group,showarrow = F)
}) %>% plotly::subplot(shareX = T, shareY = T, nrows = 1, margin = 0.001, widths = c(0.5, 0.5))
```

Which gives:
[image]

As you can see passing `col.df$text.col` to the `font` `list` in `plotly::add_annotations` is not obeyed and all text annotations are color with the same color.

Any idea how to get them colored according to `col.df$text.col`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotly's interpretations of your code led to every possible color listed for each of the 40 annotations.

So how do I know this? The first thing I did was send the plot to an object, like so:

```
lapply(c("a","b"), function(l){
  col.df <- dplyr::filter(df, col == l)
  n.text <- as.character(col.df$n)
  plotly::plot_ly(data = col.df, ygap = 1, 
                  z = ~n, x = ~col, y = ~group,
                  colors = grDevices::colorRamp(
                    c(dplyr::filter(colors.df, col == l)$fill.low, 
                      dplyr::filter(colors.df, col == l)$fill.high)), 
                  type = "heatmap") %>%
    plotly::hide_colorbar() %>%
    plotly::add_annotations(font = list(color = ~text.col, size = 8),
                            text = n.text, x = ~col,
                            y = ~group, showarrow = F)
  }) %>% 
  plotly::subplot(shareX = T, shareY = T, nrows = 1, 
                  margin = 0.001, widths = c(0.5, 0.5)) -> a
```

I wanted to view the plot object in the source pane. However, this plot wasn't a complete build, so I did that next.

```
a <- plotly_build(a)  # embed the JSON data and layout
```

Then I looked at the object again.

[image]

You can see the list of values for color in that image. So, let's help Plotly decide on one color since it seems rather indecisive today.

```
lapply(1:40,
       function(k){
         base = a$x$layout$annotations[[k]] # find the annotation
         # find the color that should be there
         col = filter(df, col == base$x, group == base$y) %>%  
           select(text.col) %>% unlist()
         # change the plotly object
         a$x$layout$annotations[[k]]$font$color <<- col
       })
a # take another look at that graph
```

[image]

This is what you wanted, but it's really hard to read!

I made the text bold to see if the legibility improved.

```
lapply(1:40,
       function(j){
         base = a$x$layout$annotations[[j]]
         t = base$text
         a$x$layout$annotations[[j]]$text <<- paste0('<b>', t, '</b>')
       })

a # any better?
```

[image]

It helped a little. I'll leave it for you to figure out. If you have any questions, let me know.